# How to rotate an image surrounded by black border?

Tags: opencv, rotation, border

The image I get from the scanner is likely the one in pic 1. What I need to get is shown in pic 2. The rotation needs be applied on the whole page, except the border. The problem is that the distance between the black border and the actual page may not be constant for the whole width of the page. That's why I can't apply the rotation directly on the image I get from the scanner, but only on the page which could have been awry scanned. The rotation needs to set the contours the most horizontal (top and bottom) and vertical (left and right). Both in pic 1 and 2 the scanned page continues on the left only for the top half. Well, I need that too. I can't cut that. 
I tried using openCV but had some problems. I'm quite familiar with it so I'd like to use it. But if you know some other solutions to achieve the same, do not hesitate! 
I just found out I'm not allowed to upload images. Ask for doubts.

Here's pic 1: http://i.cubeupload.com/RIaeV2.jpg
Here's pic 2: http://i.cubeupload.com/vIm4Me.jpg

Comment: still not sure what the task/difficulty is: Finding the right rotation angle automatically? rotate the image for known angle? rotate and crop so that the black border is removed? something completely different?

Comment: If you have a non-compressed image, like png, it would be even easier, since there will be no artifacts on the border.

Comment: Would you please post the code you'd use using the images I linked?

Comment: do you have png images or you're stuck with jpeg?

Comment: the uploading site converted them to jpg